# Reading multiple .dat files into MatLab

Tags: matlab, file, import

I am having great difficulties reading a bunch of .dat files into MatLab.  I have tried to Google the problem, but after one hour I still can't get my code to work.  In total I have 141 .dat files.  Each file consist of three lines of header information (which I do not want to include), and then a bunch of rows, each with three columns of numbers.  I want to merge the rows from all the .dat files into one large matrix featuring all the rows, and three columns (since each row in all .dat files contains three numbers).  This is the code I have attempted to use:

```
d = dir('C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\MATLAB\polygoner1\');
out = [];
N_files = numel(d);
for i = 3:N_files
    fid = fopen(d(i).name,'r');
    data = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f','HeaderLines',3);
    out = [out; data];
end
```

However, when I try to run the code I get the error message

```
??? Error using ==> textscan
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> readpoly at 6
    data = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f','HeaderLines',3);
```

If anyone knows how I can get this to work, then I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: If you read the documentation for [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), you'll see that your first input to `fopen` must be a full or relative path if the file is not in the current MATLAB directory. Use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) with your pathname and filename.

Comment: This isn't part of the question, but you should be sure to close the file when you're done by putting the statement `fclose(fid);` as the last line in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will add this to the code.  I have done quite a lot of MatLab in university courses, but now when I need to use it at work there all these challenges with transferring files between various software!  That was not taught :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you use `fopen`, you are not giving the full path of the file

```
path = 'C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\MATLAB\polygoner1\'
d = dir(path);

....

%as @craigim advised it, otherwise you can use strcat
my_file = fullfile(path, {d.name}) 
for i = 3:N_files
    fid = fopen(my_file{i},'r');

    ....

    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: Better to use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) to concatenate the directory and file name because it has internal checks to make sure that the file separators are present and correct for a particular filesystem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  MatLab now runs the program without errors!  Really appreciate it!

Comment: @craigim : didn't know about this particular function, it look wiser to use it over strcat! Edited my question

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have changed my code accordingly.

Comment: One last suggestion. `fullfile` will operate on a list and can be taken out of the loop. `my_file = fullfile(path, {d.name});` ... `fid = fopen(my_file{i}, 'r');`